# What is the correct way to get data from CLI program located on other server?

Tags: bash, server

I have main App on virtual machine (VM1, PHP-app). I need to get info from CLI program on other VM (VM2). My CLI program - tesseract (but instead of tesseract may be other CLI program). VM1 need send some data for program on VM2, for example, 'NEED_CATS', and program on VM2 need return result by executing something like this in command line in ssh session:

```
tesseract input.tiff output --oem 1 -l eng
```

.
Scheme:

[image: Scheme]

How to organize this communication?

I understand, if on VM2 was php-script instead of cli program I need to send HTTP-request from VM1 and install nginx on VM2, which transfer data to php-script and return result.

In my case I also need for nginx?
How get data from cli program on other server?

Comment: Just use `ssh`. So if on VM1 and you want to run something on VM2, use `ssh user@VM2 cli-program parameter`

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Are there other variants, where VM1 won't have ssh access?

Comment: There are many ways. You could wrap the CLI program on VM2 in a couple of lines of `netcat` that wait forever in a loop for a command then run the program and return the results via `netcat`. You could let VM1 and VM2 share access to Dropbox and VM1 could place a file in Dropbox that VM2 sees and processes. You could put a little Redis instance somewhere and do a BLPOP in VM2 waiting for a command and an LPUSH on VM1 with a command to run...

Comment: Or instead of Dropbox, just use a filesystem shared between the 2 VMs - it could be somewhere on the host or NFS/Samba shared between the two VMs.